# Upgrading Rails 3 to Rails 4 rake tasks "Don't know how to build task"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm upgrading a Rails 3 application to Rails 4 and had existing plugins using the old vendor/plugins directory.  Where possible I have switched to gems, in other cases I have moved these to lib and created initializers in config/initializers.

Some of these plugins add rake tasks that now are failing with the error "Don't know how to build task 'X' where `X` is any task that was migrated to the lib directory.  Is there some other steps that need to be taken to migrate rake tasks when upgrading to Rails 4?

Comment: does
`bundle exec rake`
get the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Rails vendor plugin style would put rake tasks into a lib/tasks sub-folder under the plugins sub-directory.  The old file structure looked something like this.

```
/vendor/plugins/plugin1/lib/tasks/foo.rake
/vendor/plugins/plugin2/lib/tasks/bar.rake
```

Rails 4 did away with support for plugins so you needed to switch to gems or move the plugins to the lib sub-directory and create an initializer.  This gives a new directory structure for the rake tasks that looks something like this.

```
/lib/plugin1/lib/tasks/foo.rake
/lib/plugin2/lib/tasks/bar.rake
```

To pick up these rake tasks, but keep the structure so that it stays packaged with the plugin you can add the following line to Rakefile.

```
Dir["lib/**/lib/tasks/**/*.rake"].each{ |r| load r }
```